# Pandas resample dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a resampling (downsampling) problem that should be straightforward to do but I'm not able!!
Here is a simplified example:

```
df:  
       Time         A
0   0.01591  0.108929
1   0.27973  0.411764
2   0.55044  0.064253
3   0.81386  0.317394
4   1.07983  0.722707
5   1.35051  1.154193
6   1.61495  1.151492
7   1.88035  0.123389
8   2.15462  0.093583
9   2.41534  0.260944
10  2.67992  1.007564
11  2.95148  0.325353
12  3.21364  0.555593
13  3.47980  0.740621
15  4.01519  1.619669
16  4.28679  0.477371
17  4.55482  0.432049
18  4.81570  0.194224
19  5.07992  0.331936
```

The Time column is in seconds. I would like to make the Time column the index and downsample the dataframe to 1s. Help please?

Comment: How do you do the resampling? What's your expected value for Time 1.0s?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reindex` and choose one fill method

```
In [37]: df.set_index('Time').reindex(range(0,6), method='bfill')
Out[37]: 
          A
0  0.108929
1  0.722707
2  0.093583
3  0.555593
4  1.619669
5  0.331936
```

Comment: Yes, works fine for a range of limited length. Additional question though. Whan I pass the length of the real A vector in my dataset it does not work. Strange!! There is no problem passing ot to the range function itself, but when I pass it into the expression you suggested I get NAN in A as a result...any idea?

Comment: What is the range for you data set?

Answer (score 0):

First convert your index to datetime format:

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.Time,unit='s')
```

Then [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling) by second (this is the mean value by default but can be changed to sum etc - e.g. add `how='sum'` as parameter):

```
d.resample('S')

                         Time         A
Time                                   
1970-01-01 00:00:00  0.414985  0.225585
1970-01-01 00:00:01  1.481410  0.787945
1970-01-01 00:00:02  2.550340  0.421861
1970-01-01 00:00:03  3.346720  0.648107
1970-01-01 00:00:04  4.418125  0.680828
1970-01-01 00:00:05  5.079920  0.331936
```

The year/date can be changed if important.